# Group by and check field for each group pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data:

```
  ne_type     ru_type du_type  pass_all
0   CDU50  MMU (MT1A)      DU         0
1     vDU  MMU (MT1A)     vDU         0
2   CDU50  MMU (MT2A)      DU         0
3   CDU50  MMU (MT2A)      DU         0
4   CDU50  MMU (MT2A)      DU         1
5     vDU  MMU (MT3A)     vDU         0
```

And How can I group by 2 fields ru_type and du_type and count total pass for group is 0, total of group is 4
After group by ru_type, du_type

```
ru_type     du_type    pass_all
MMU (MT1A)  DU         0
            vDU        0
MMU (MT2A)  DU         0
MMU (MT3A)  vDU        0
```

Another data:

```
  ru_type ne_type project__package customer  stepfpga__action_fpga_du_start  ...  in_progress_stepfpga  in_progress_steppackagerelease  in_progress_stepcellsetup  in_progress_steptm  in_progress_stepsens
0       -    ACPF           SVR22B   AIRTEL                              -1  ...                     0                               0                          0                   0                     0
1       -    ACPF           SVR22B   AIRTEL                               0  ...                     0                               0                          0                   0                     0
2       -    ACPF           SVR22B   AIRTEL                               0  ...                     0                               0                          0                   0                     0
3       -    ACPF           SVR22B   AIRTEL                               0  ...                     0                               0                          0                   0                     0
```

Code

```
def check_delay_or_progress2(row):
    # print(row)
    if row['in_progress_stepsens'] == 0:
        return 0
    # for step in order_step[::-1]:
    #     if row['delay_' + step] == 1:
    #         return 1
    #     elif row['in_progress_' + step] == 1:
    #         return 0
    return 1

# print(ne_pd)
ne_pd['in_progress_steptm'] = ne_pd.apply(lambda x: check_delay_or_progress2(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

No sure I got the logic but do you want?

```
df.groupby(['ru_type','du_type'])['pass_all'].all().astype(int)
```

output:

```
ru_type     du_type
MMU (MT1A)  DU         0
            vDU        0
MMU (MT2A)  DU         0
MMU (MT3A)  vDU        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test if all values are `1` per groups, working well if only `0` and `1` values:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ru_type','du_type'])['pass_all'].all().astype(int).reset_index()
print (df1)
      ru_type du_type  pass_all
0  MMU (MT1A)      DU         0
1  MMU (MT1A)     vDU         0
2  MMU (MT2A)      DU         0
3  MMU (MT3A)     vDU         0
```

If need test not `0` values:

```
df2 = (df.assign(pass_all = df['pass_all'].ne(0))
         .groupby(['ru_type','du_type'])['pass_all'].all()
         .astype(int)
         .reset_index())
```